# Network Management Software - What does it really need?

Tags: c#

Been tasked for my job to build a Network Management Software to manage a school network...

We built one before and it had stuff like Server Ping'ing and Integration with WMI for RAM etc

We also really want to manage our PCs (About 500ish) along with our Mobile Devices, so it needs to integrate with AD, which it does very well at the moment.

What other features do you think this type of software needs? Like does it need SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) for Switches and APs?

(It is being built in C#, so the things need to be available for .NET or I will have to use P/Invoke etc)

Cheers
Richard

Comment: You need to get a list of requirements.

Answer (score 1):

SNMP is pretty key. It'll allow you to discover devices (via querying arp caches via SNMP to discover devices and using the standard info to determine what they are). Virtually everything connected to the network will support SNMP in some capacity.

Most devices will also support info specific to them via their SNMP enterprise MIB. e.g. printers will report trays, ink levels etc.

If you have SNMP query capability, I suspect you'll end up with a ton of metrics that you can gather and display at your leisure.

Finally, do you need to build this ? A lot of [free solutions exist](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-free-network-monitoring-tools/1342), and those I've investigated are extensible through plugins, user-scripts etc.

Comment: I think building in SNMP is key then, thanks :)